# Write the series using sigma notation: $f(x)= 1 - (x^2)/2! + (x^4)/4! - (x^6)/6! +\cdots$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, notation

$$f(x)= 1 - (x^2)/2! + (x^4)/4! - (x^6)/6! + \cdots$$

I don't know how to get the signs to work like negative, then positive. I have tried to make it like the following:

$(-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^{2n-1}}{ (2n-2)!}$

However, the first term's denominator will be $0!$ which does not work out.

Comment: $0!=1$ in every context.  Yes it does.  Note that the powers of $x$ as you have written them are even, whereas $2n-1$ is always odd.  Do you not mean to use instead $2n-2$?  Are you treating the initial term as when $n=0$ or as when $n=1$?  (it is more common to see it as $n=0$)

Comment: I completely forgot about 0!=1. I am treating the initial as n=1 because it is easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for this: $(-1)^nx^{2n}$.

One may recall that
$$
\cos x= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}
$$ giving
$$
f(x)=\cos x.
$$

Comment: you went one step further than my question and it really helped! thank you!

Comment: @Sohee You are welcome.